# Select exclusive list of list of objects based on object properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of a class that contains another list of a different class, example:

```cs
public class jobs
{
    public int jobID {get;set;}
    public string jobName {get;set;}
}

public class jobSteps
{
    public int stepID {get;set;}
    public string stepDescription {get;set;}
    public int stepOrder {get; set;}
    public List<jobs> jobCollection {get; set;}
}
```

I can have an N size list of 'jobSteps', and each 'jobStep' can have an N size list of 'jobs', however, the same 'job' can be in more than one 'step', usually in an ascending 'stepOrder'.

How can I create a list of 'jobSteps', that only contains the job at the last 'step' that it is present in, in other words, the Max 'stepOrder'?

I have the following function that iterated over each 'jobStep' list, and then selects only the jobIDs where they aren't in a later 'stepOrder', for example.

```cs
public class myFunctions
{
    public void getJobLatestStep()
    {
        // Example Data:
        List<jobSteps> jobStepCollection = new List<jobSteps>
        {
            new jobSteps()
            {
                stepID = 1,
                stepDescription = "Start",
                stepOrder = 0,
                jobCollection = new List<jobs>()
                {
                    new jobs() { jobID = 1, jobName = "Cook food" },
                    new jobs() { jobID = 2, jobName = "Do laundry" },
                    new jobs() { jobID = 3, jobName = "Go to work" }
                }
            },
            new jobSteps()
            {
                stepID = 2,
                stepDescription = "Continue",
                stepOrder = 1,
                jobCollection = new List<jobs>()
                {
                    new jobs() { jobID = 1, jobName = "Cook food" },
                    new jobs() { jobID = 2, jobName = "Do laundry" }
                }
            },
            new jobSteps()
            {
                stepID = 3,
                stepDescription = "Finalise",
                stepOrder = 2,
                jobCollection = new List<jobs>()
                {
                    new jobs() { jobID = 2, jobName = "Do laundry" }
                }
            }
        };

        List<jobSteps> lastStepOfJob = new List<jobSteps> {};
        foreach (jobSteps c in jobStepCollection )
        {
            jobSteps currentStep = c;

            for (int i = jobStepCollection.IndexOf(c); i < jobStepCollection.Count() - 1; i++){
                currentStep.jobCollection = currentStep.jobCollection.Where(x => !jobStepCollection[i].jobCollection.Select(z => z.jobID).ToList().Contains(x.jobID)).ToList();
            };

            lastStepOfJob.Add(currentStep);
        };
    }

    //The desired result would be:
    //stepID = 1
    //stepDescription = 'Start'
    //stepOrder = 0
        //jobID = 3
        //jobName = 'Go to work'

    //stepID = 2
    //stepDescription = 'Continue'
    //stepOrder = 1
        //jobID = 1
        //jobName = 'Cook food'

    //stepID = 3
    //stepDescription = 'Finalise'
    //stepOrder = 2
        //jobID = 2
        //jobName = 'Do laundry'
}
```

How can I write this using only LINQ if possible, as I will have to handle large amounts of data at a given time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you strictly want to use the built in LINQ operators it is going to be kind of convoluted.  This will work:

```
List<jobSteps> lastStepOfJob =
    jobStepCollection
    .SelectMany(x => x.jobCollection.Select(y => new { JobStep = x, Job = y }))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Job.jobID)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.JobStep.stepOrder).Select(y => new { JobStep = y.JobStep, Job = y.Job }).First())
    .GroupBy(x => x.JobStep.stepOrder)
    .Select(x => new { JobStep = x.First().JobStep, Jobs = x.Select(y => y.Job) })
    .Select(x => new jobSteps()
    {
        stepDescription = x.JobStep.stepDescription,
        stepID = x.JobStep.stepID,
        stepOrder = x.JobStep.stepOrder,
        jobCollection = x.Jobs.OrderBy(y => y.jobID).Select(y => new jobs() { jobID = y.jobID, jobName = y.jobName }).ToList()
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.stepOrder)
    .ToList();
```

Basically, you want to:

- flatten your list
- group by the job id
- select the first job step for each job
- group by your job step order
- finally, 'rehydrate' your list

In this example I am creating entirely new `jobs` and `jobSteps` objects to avoid side effects.

If you were to roll your own extension method I am sure you would get better performance.  If I have time later tonight I will show an example implementation.

**EDIT - Additional approach**

Here is a slight twist on the above approach that I think could give you little better performance.  I am essentially replacing the first `GroupBy` with an aggregate function that keeps a memo.

```
List<jobSteps> lastStepOfJob =
    jobStepCollection
    .SelectMany(x => x.jobCollection.Select(y => Tuple.Create(y, x)))
    .Aggregate(
        new Dictionary<int, Tuple<jobs, jobSteps>>(),
        (memo, value) =>
        {
            if (memo.ContainsKey(value.Item1.jobID))
            {
                if (memo[value.Item1.jobID].Item2.stepOrder < value.Item2.stepOrder)
                {
                    memo[value.Item1.jobID] = value;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                memo.Add(value.Item1.jobID, value);
            }
            return memo;
        })
    .Select(x => new { Job = x.Value.Item1, JobStep = x.Value.Item2 })
    .GroupBy(x => x.JobStep.stepOrder)
    .Select(x => new { JobStep = x.First().JobStep, Jobs = x.Select(y => y.Job) })
    .Select(x => new jobSteps()
    {
        stepDescription = x.JobStep.stepDescription,
        stepID = x.JobStep.stepID,
        stepOrder = x.JobStep.stepOrder,
        jobCollection = x.Jobs.OrderBy(y => y.jobID).Select(y => new jobs() { jobID = y.jobID, jobName = y.jobName }).ToList()
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.stepOrder)
    .ToList();
```

The strategy is essentially the same strategy as my first solution.  I know it looks a little intimidating.  It could probably be simplified a little if you override the `GetHashCode` method for the `jobs` and `jobSteps` types or implemented custom `IEqualityComparer`s.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. This was a sample question that I took from my actual code (which I cannot post due to Intellectual Property reasons). Please, an example would be much appreciated, as performance will be a big factor as I would need to process thousands of records a day and warehouse them. (And I am not too experienced with Linq to be honest).

Answer (score 1):

Using your sample collection I came up with this solution:

```
var jobIds = new List<int>();
var results = jobStepCollection
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.stepOrder)
    .Select(x =>
    {
        var localJobIds = x.jobCollection.Select(y => y.jobID);
        var newIds = localJobIds.Where(y => !jobIds.Contains(y));
        var newJobs = x.jobCollection.Where(y => newIds.Contains(y.jobID));

        x.jobCollection = newJobs.ToList();
        jobIds.AddRange(newIds);
        return x;
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.stepOrder)
    .ToList();
```

I get the list, sort the steps in reverse order. Then I check job's ID. I keep track of all the IDs I encountered. If the ID is a new one - keep the job in the collection. Otherwise ignore it. Add newly found IDs to the IDs collection.

The result is what you expected:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I am currently running benchmarks on both approaches to see which will be able to handle a bigger bulk amount of data. If I may inquire, what tool did you use to have a visual display of the list contents?

Comment: It's LinqPad. If you write a collection to a console you will get this view: `Console.WriteLine(results);`.